# How to match ArrayList string value with the XDocument Title attribute using c# 2.0

Tags: xml, c#-2.0

I have got below XML format string as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tcm:ListKeywords xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" Managed="1024">
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:229-552514-1024" Type="1024" Title="Aalborg" Lock="0" IsRoot="true"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:229-552512-1024" Type="1024" Title="Aarhus" Lock="0" IsRoot="true"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:229-329379-1024" Type="1024" Title="Aberdeen" Lock="0" IsRoot="true"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:229-569711-1024" Type="1024" Title="Abha" Lock="0" IsRoot="true"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:229-192866-1024" Type="1024" Title="Abidjan" Lock="0" IsRoot="true"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:229-569704-1024" Type="1024" Title="Abilene" Lock="0" IsRoot="true"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:229-192850-1024" Type="1024" Title="Abu Dhabi" Lock="0" IsRoot="true"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:229-192888-1024" Type="1024" Title="Accra" Lock="0" IsRoot="true"/>
</tcm:ListKeywords>
```

Now I am having Arraylist of strings, I want to write a function which will take above XML string as a parameter as well as my Arraylist string and will match with XML //Item Title attribute, for example as below:

```
public bool matchArrayWithXMLTitle(Xmldocument xDoc, string str)
{
    If (//Item/Title == str)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
}
```

Then I will be using it as below code

`bool matchStr = matchArrayWithXMLTitle(xDoc,"Abidjan");` //Should return true as Abidjan is there in XML

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below solution worked for me.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string xmlListKeywords = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
                    <tcm:ListKeywords xmlns:tcm=""http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"" Managed=""1024"">
                      <tcm:Item ID=""tcm:229-552514-1024"" Type=""1024"" Title=""Aalborg"" Lock=""0"" IsRoot=""true""/>
                      <tcm:Item ID=""tcm:229-552512-1024"" Type=""1024"" Title=""Aarhus"" Lock=""0"" IsRoot=""true""/>
                      <tcm:Item ID=""tcm:229-329379-1024"" Type=""1024"" Title=""Aberdeen"" Lock=""0"" IsRoot=""true""/>
                      <tcm:Item ID=""tcm:229-569711-1024"" Type=""1024"" Title=""Abha"" Lock=""0"" IsRoot=""true""/>
                      <tcm:Item ID=""tcm:229-192866-1024"" Type=""1024"" Title=""Abidjan"" Lock=""0"" IsRoot=""true""/>
                      <tcm:Item ID=""tcm:229-569704-1024"" Type=""1024"" Title=""Abilene"" Lock=""0"" IsRoot=""true""/>
                      <tcm:Item ID=""tcm:229-192850-1024"" Type=""1024"" Title=""Abu Dhabi"" Lock=""0"" IsRoot=""true""/>
                      <tcm:Item ID=""tcm:229-192888-1024"" Type=""1024"" Title=""Accra"" Lock=""0"" IsRoot=""true""/>
                    </tcm:ListKeywords>";
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.LoadXml(xmlListKeywords);

            bool bMatch = matchArrayWithXMLTitle(xdoc, "Abidjan");
            bMatch = matchArrayWithXMLTitle(xdoc, "Test");

        }

        public static bool matchArrayWithXMLTitle(XmlDocument xDoc, string str)
        {
            XmlNode targetNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//*[@Title = '" + str + "']");
            if (targetNode != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Please suggest for any issues.

Thanks.

M.S